# Equivalent method in java (numpy.random.normal(mean,var))

Tags: java, normal-distribution

Is there any method in java that is equivalent to `numpy.random.normal(mean,variance)`.

Comment: And what language is `numpy.random.normal(mean,variance)` a part of?

Comment: He meant [math things](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html#numpy.random.normal) I think. You should search for whats inside that link.

Comment: This is third party library of python.

Comment: Both Question and Accepted answer needs to be modified. Scaling should be done with standard deviation and not variance. It is very confusing given the fact that variance = square(standard deviation). Unfortunately my edits to question and answer were rejected, so adding it as comment. 
Correct python version: `numpy.random.normal(mean,std_dev)` , 
Correct Java version:  `double randomValue = mean + r.nextGaussian()*std_dev;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `java.util.Random` class:

```
Random r = new Random();
double randomValue = mean + r.nextGaussian()*std_dev;
```

Note that if you need multiple random values, you can use `r` multiple times. You can also supply the constructor with a specific seed `Random r = new Random(1234);`.

Comment: @user451937 Glad I could help. Would you consider choosing an answer? You can do this by clicking the checkmark on the left side of the corresponding question. Doesn't have to be mine, just choose the one that answers the question the best (from your perspective).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to get a random samples from a gaussian distribution.

You can use java.util.Random class for that :

```
private double getGaussian(double mean, double variance){
      return mean + new Random().nextGaussian() * variance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with [`Random.getGaussian()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian%28%29)
or [this](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/api/cc/mallet/util/Randoms.html#nextGaussian%28double,%20double%29)